# How to use remember & mutableStateOf seperately?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, compose-recomposition

Usually, compose codes are like

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun BuildMyView() {
    val counter = rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(1) }

    Text(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .wrapContentSize(align = Alignment.Center)
            .clickable { counter.value++ },// click and text will ++
        text = "${counter.value}"
    )
}
```

Recently, I want to collect all view data together and build a state and create sth like:

```
data class MyState(
    val data: MutableState<String>
)

val stateTemp = MyState(mutableStateOf("hello"))

@Preview
@Composable
fun BuildMyView() {
    val counter = rememberSaveable { stateTemp.data}

    Text(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .wrapContentSize(align = Alignment.Center)
            .clickable { stateTemp.data.value += "-1" },
        text = counter.value
    )
}
```

In second case, when I click text, it does ++ but if I go to a new page and come back, all changes will lost however in first case it doesn't.

I then read some compose codes and get confusing since I didn't find where remember subscribe a mutable state.

Is there a method to make mutable state out of compose work?

Beside, is somewhere I can find codes generated by compose under my gradle build dir or anywhere else (except dex, that's too hard to read)? Compose really did amazing job but I cannot read the real codes running and that makes much more difficult for freshman to get start.

**UPDATE ON 2022/6/15**

Now I found a proper solution to use viewmodel instead of state holder and use mutableState in viewmodel and subscribe state in view composable part so that I can avoid complex grammar of viewmodel with livedata. Hope that will help followers.

Comment: One more point confusing me is that mutablestate in compose currently looks different with outside and I guess google did sth with ksp. If it is, why don't they mark mutableState as composable?

Comment: I'm just beginning to learn Compose myself, so I might be wrong, but I think @Composeable is used only for functions that are called during recomposition. The lambdas passed to the various `remember` functions are called only during the first composition event, and then the same instance is returned in subsequent recompositions. Your strategy above won't work because you're  passing `stateTemp.data` as an instance. The remembered instance is the data--it has no way of being updated from `stateTemp`. Since it's "saveable" it might not even remain as the same instance because it can be recreated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I then read some compose codes and get confusing since I didn't find where remember subscribe a mutable state.

As far as I understand, `remember` calculates and caches what ever is inside its `lambda` during the first `composition` or first execution of the `@composable` function only, this is the only thing that the `@composable` remembers or subscribes on. Unless you provide a `key` to a `remember`, that when it changed, it will trigger a `re-calculation` to be `remembered`

> Is there a method to make mutable state out of compose work?

Do you mean some piece of non composable code or function that will automatically trigger when this `State` object is changed? If this is what you mean, I suppose you just have to resort back to good old observable patterns

As far as I understand, compose `States` are specifically designed to work with the underlying `Snapshot` system where the heart of triggering the `composition` mechanism happens, I can't imagine (so far) any usage of `State` objects outside of composition or outside of the `Snapshot` system.

> In second case, when I click text, it does ++ but if I go to a new page and come back, all changes will lost however in first case it doesn't.

As for using `rememberSaveable`, I would be careful using it , it might look the same as `remember` with just an additional power of `saving/restoration`, but it has more power with equal responsibilities imposed to it that you have to take into account when using it. I haven't used or defined a `rememberSaveable` object without defining a `Saver` in it explicitly, so I can only assume in your case here

```
rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(1) }
```

the `composable` observes a `rememberSaveable` that also observes an actual object that actually `changes` and implicitly saves and restores that object with the most recent value

while in this, I think

```
data class MyState(
    val data: MutableState<String>
)

val stateTemp = MyState(mutableStateOf("hello"))
...
...
rememberSaveable { stateTemp.data}
```

`rememberSaveable` saves the state of the `val data: MutableState<String>` (which is empty), while the `composable` observes an instance of a `mutableState` that is changing, unfortunately `rememberSaveable` already saved an initial state in way like this `rememberSaveable { data: MutableState<String> }` not the actual `mutableStateOf("hello")` that changes, so it will restore it that way when you go back.

I'm curious, you can try implementing your **MyState** class with a companion object holding a `Saver` where you can define how `rememberSaveable` will `Save` and `Restore` the data, I think it will restore it when you navigate back to that screen. When you debug a `Saver` implementation, you will also notice that the `restoration` is invoked during recomposition. Im not quite sure though

Disclaimer: Im just learning compose recently and still digging deeper about the `Snapshot` system, and it seemed like you're heading in the same direction as I do. I'd recommend to visit this [link](https://dev.to/zachklipp/introduction-to-the-compose-snapshot-system-19cn) once in a while if your'e interested in the `Snapshot` system. Apologies as well, I can't comment yet due to lack of reputation so I just posted my thought and current understanding of how `State` and `composition` work together.

Comment: Thanks but I think saver won't work, sth I did't show is time to create state and this is currently in composable field and will be recomposed, according to google's suggestion, I am going to improve my state to extends ViewModel and get data lifecycle which I want